# Switch not being checked correctly onCreateView

Tags: android, android-fragments, switch-statement

I have a switch in a Fragment, whose state depend on the user's actions on this fragment, but also on other fragments.
Therefore, the state is loaded as follows in **onCreateView()**:

```
    switch_show_label = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.switch_showlabel);
    switch_show_label.setChecked(mListener.isShowLabelChecked());
    print("show label is: " + mListener.isShowLabelChecked() + " " + switch_show_label.isChecked());
    switch_show_label.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

When the boolean corresponding to the state is changed in another fragment, I can read:

```
SettingsFragment: show label is: true true
```

Yet the switch is visually **switched off**, and the value "false" is sent back to the main activity...

How can this happen?
THanks.

Comment: let's try something here, what would happen if you move `switch_show_label.setChecked(mListener.isShowLabelChecked());` to `onViewCreated`

Comment: where is onViewCreated in the Fragment lifecycle? http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
I have done a small test, and the change is called after onActivityCreated()

Comment: it's called immediately after onCreateView try to implement it should be better than on resume solution, [check it here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so far I only found this trick:

in **onCreateView()**

```
realSwitchState=mListener.isShowLabelChecked();
```

in **onResume()**

```
switch_show_label.setChecked(realSwitchState);
```

But there should be a nicer solution, shouldn't there?